# Error encountered when running OpenCV line drawing script

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying out some OpenCV code for a robot to navigate a maze. I am able to detect the edges of the walls of the maze and now for testing, I want to try and draw some imaginary lines halfway between each edge that has been detected. This will then be the driving line.

Each line found has a start and end point defined by x1, y1 and x2, y2

The code snippet below attempts to create the coordinates for the center lines and assign them to variables `ptx1`, `pty1`, `ptx2` and `pty2`. The math is probably wrong but I am getting a `TypeError` and need some help fixing it.

Here is the error:

> TypeError: integer argument expected, got float

The error is pointing to the last line:

```
for line in lines:
for x1,y1,x2,y2 in line:
    print(x1)
    print(y1)
    ptx1 = (x1+800)/2
    pty1 = (y1+600)/2
    ptx2 = (x2+800)/2
    pty2 = (y2+600)/2

    cv2.line(lines_edges, (ptx1,pty1),(ptx2,pty2), (0,0,255), 5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variables `ptx1, pty1, ptx2 and pty2` are floats, the function expects integers. Transtype them in integer using the `int()` function:

```
ptx1 = int((x1 + 800)/2)
```

Or use the following syntax:

```
ptx1 = (x1 + 800) // 2
```

Comment: Thanks very much, once I added the int() function as suggested it worked fine, well the error disappeared :-)